# SQL - adding column A depending on value in column B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add the values in a column based on the value in another. But the output is not what I am expecting. Any help tweeking this query would be helpful.
Example:

```
SELECT [custNo]
  ,[cityNo]
  ,sum([TransactionCount]) as transcount
FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary]
where [format] = 23
or [format] = 25
or [format] = 38
or [format] >=400 and [format] <= 499
or [format] >=800 and [format] <= 899
and transactiondate = '6/21/16'
group by custno, cityno
```

Will result in an output such as:

```
custno  cityno  transcount
1       10220   4
1       10277   6
501     10284   9
501     10284   17
604     10248   4
604     10248   317
```

What I'd like to have as the output is more like:

```
custno  cityno  transcount
1       10220   4
1       10277   6
501     10284   26 (sum of 17+9)
604     10248   321 (sum of 317+4)
```

Comment: I fail to see how a query like this can possibly yield an output like the one cited above.

Comment: Since you are grouping by `custno` and `cityno`, I don't think you should be getting those duplicates.    What data type is cityno?  Any chance its a string with a space in it?

Comment: Not related to the question but you should use `[format] IN (23, 25, 38) or [format] between 400 and 499`

Comment: Include sample data so we can understand how that output was generated.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Can you check if you possibly have spaces or something in those fields? I can't see how the grouping would split those up otherwise...

Comment: You shouldn't get duplicates only if cityno doesn't intersect with Custno. If it does then the records wont be aggregated. Alternatively you could use a derive table to apply your aggregation function on one column and then join it with the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store your distinct data in table variable..

   ```
   declare @Table Table(ID int identity, custNo int, cityNo int, Other varchar(500))

   insert into @Table(custNo, cityNo)
      SELECT distinct 
          [custNo], [cityNo]
      FROM 
          [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary]
      WHERE
          [format] = 23
          or [format] = 25
          or [format] = 38
          or [format] >= 400 and [format] <= 499
          or [format] >= 800 and [format] <= 899
          and transactiondate = '6/21/16'
   ```
2. Use while loop to store your description in `Other` column using `COALESCE` function

   ```
   declare @i int, @cnt int, @custNo  int
   declare @Result VARCHAR(Max) 

   select @cnt = count(*), @i = 1 
   from @Table

   while @i <= @cnt
   begin
       select @custNo = custNo 
       from @Table 
       where ID = @i

      (if select count(*)  FROM TransactionSummary where custNo =@custNo )>1
   ```

   begin
      set @Result =''
      SELECT  @Result = COALESCE(@Result + '+', '') + cast(TransactionCount as varchar(50))
      FROM TransactionSummary where custNo =@custNo 
      update @Table set Other ='(sum of '+@Result + ')' where id=@id
   end
     set @i=@i+1
   end
3. Finally write your query..

   SELECT [tr.custNo]
     ,[tr.cityNo]
    ,cast(sum([tr.TransactionCount]) as varchar(50)) + isnull(Other,'' ) transcount
   FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary] tr
   left outer join @Table t on tr.custNo=t.custNo and tr.cityNo=t.cityNo
   where [format] = 23
   or [format] = 25
   or [format] = 38
   or [format] >=400 and [format] <= 499
   or [format] >=800 and [format] <= 899
   and transactiondate = '6/21/16'
   group by custno, cityno

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
SELECT [custNo]
  ,[cityNo]
  ,SUM(TransactionCount) over (Partition by CustNo) as 'SUM' as transcount
FROM [log].[dbo].[TransactionSummary]
where [format] = 23
or [format] = 25
or [format] = 38
or [format] >=400 and [format] <= 499
or [format] >=800 and [format] <= 899
and transactiondate = '6/21/16'
group by custno, cityno
```